# Redirect browser to a different website when you visit a certain website?

Tags: firefox, website, redirection

I am having this problem with yahoo mail. When I log out of my email, it takes me to yahoo.com homepage instead of the yahoo login website. What I want to do is that when the yahoo.com website is reached, it will skip displaying the yahoo.com website and display the https://login.yahoo.com/ website instead.

Comment: I can get you a working solution if you accept the fact that you will *never* be able to visit the yahoo.com site (at least until you disable the solution I provide).

Comment: OK what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Greasemonkey should do it: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Use this script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        yahoo.com to login.yahoo.com
// @description Redirects yahoo.com to login.yahoo.com
// @include     http://yahoo.com/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
    if(content.document.location == "http://yahoo.com"){
            window.location.replace("http://login.yahoo.com")
}
```

Comment: script didn't work

Answer (score 1):

First install the [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) add-on.

Then access the redirector configuration page by clicking on the Redirector button or entering this url directly in the address bar `resource://redirector-at-einaregilsson-dot-com/redirector.html`.

On the Redirector page, create a redirect with the following configuration and save it:

> **Description:** *[Any identifiable text you like]*
>   **Example URL:** yahoo.com
>   **Include Pattern:** `(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?yahoo.com`
>   **Redirect To:** https://login.yahoo.com
>   **Pattern Type:** Regular Expression
>
> [image: Screenshot of Redirect described above]

Now, you will be redirected to the login.yahoo.com page any time you enter any URL that matches the regular expression in the *include pattern*. You can view the yahoo.com site by disabling redirector via its button's popup menu.